# Only Keys stored not objects with refrence to that key

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, riak

I have created one method "saveInDB" which will takes 3 parameters which are passed to "imgData()" class from where all values are set to object "picDetail" of that class when i push to store to riak database only keys are stored but objects of picDetail are not being stored. I can't figure it out what's happening.

```
val riakClient = RiakFactory.pbcClient
 val bucketName = riakClient.createBucket("bucket_name").execute

def saveInDB(title: String, desc: String, imageName: String ): Boolean = {
        val picDetail = new imgData()
        picDetail.title = title
        picDetail.desc = desc
        val s = imageName.replace(".png", "")
        picDetail.imageName = imageName

        try{
            riakBucketName.store(s , picDetail).execute
            true
        }catch{
          case e: Exception => false
        }
      }
```

@Update: Riak Version : **1.3.2** and Riak Java Client : **1.1.4**

Any idea will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the Riak Client and Riak versions!!??

Comment: if you retrieve the key using curl, what do you get back?

Comment: I only get the key that i have stored, but the object associated with that key is not being stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Just found out another easy way to store.

def saveInDB(title: String, desc:String, imageName: String ): Boolean ={
        val obj = ImgData(title, desc, imageName)
        val s:String = imageName.replace(".png", "")
        val jsonString: String = generate(obj)
        var riakObject = RiakObjectBuilder.
          newBuilder("bucket_name", s).
          withContentType("application/json").
          withValue(jsonString).
          build
         try{
           riakBucketName.store(s, riakObject).returnBody(true).execute
           fetchUserData(userID)
           true
         }catch{
           case e: Exception => e
         }
        true
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the Solution as i tried to pass object "picDetail" to riak it is unable to store so i convert the object into json String. Now it is working fine. My code is like

```
case class ImgData(
    title: String,
    desc: String,
    imageName: String
)

  def getJsonString(title:String, desc:String, imageName:String) : String = {

    import play.api.libs.json._
    import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

   implicit val cardsWrites: Writes[CardsModel] = (
    (__ \ "title").write[String] and
    (__ \ "desc").write[String] and
    (__ \ "imageName").write[String]
    )(unlift(ImgData.unapply)) 
    val jObject = (title, desc, imageName)
    val jString = Json.toJson(jObject)
    jString.toString
}

  def saveInDB(title: String, desc:String, imageName: String ): Boolean ={
    val obj:String = getJsonString(title, desc, imageName)
     val s:String = imageName.replace(".png", "")
     try{
         riakBucketName.store(s ,obj).execute
        true
     }catch{
       case e: Exception => false
     }
    true
  }
```

Thank you!